# ibeacons and geofencing combined swift

Tags: ios, swift, ibeacon, geofencing

I am using both geofencing and beacons in my swift project. But their entered and exit method clash everytime I enter or leave any of the region. To be more specific, how can I execute different method to corresponding beacon or geofence region ??e.g.
I want to show a notification when the user enters the geofence region and display other page when it enters the beacon region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geofence regions and beacon regions are both regions, so the same `didEnterRegion` method is called to notify you about both. You need to write your `didEnterRegion` method to check the class of the region with an `if` statement. (I forget the syntax for that in Swift.)

### EDIT:

The Objective-C code would be

```
if ([region isMemeberOfClass: [CLBeaconRegion class]])
{
  //beacon code
}
else
{
  //geofence code
}
```

You could certainly convert that to Swift syntax, but David Young showed the better way in his comment, below:

```
if let beaconRegion = region as? CLBeaconRegion
{
  //beacon code
}
else
{
  //geofence code
}
```

(Thanks David. Answering technical questions from my iPad, before I've had coffee, is only of limited use.)

Comment: Thanks Duncan
Can you tell me the syntax in any other language, I'll covert it ...

Comment: This is correct.  In Swift you can tell if your `region`is a `CLBeaconRegion` with `if let beaconRegion = region as? CLBeaconRegion {  /* beacon code here */  } else { /* geofence code here */ }`

Comment: No worries. If this answers your question you should click the checkbox to accept it.